# Hibernate many-to-many delete

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relationship in NHibernate between two classes `Actor` and `Movie`.

```
public ActionResult removeMovieFromActor(int MovieId, int ActorId)
{
    ViewData["SectionTitle"] = "Usunięcie filmu";
    ActorsRepository ar = new ActorsRepository();

    Actor act = ar.getActor(ActorId);

    // What to do here?

    return RedirectToAction("listMovies");
}
```

How can I remove a `Movie` from `act.Movies` and make that persistent to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing more of your model and how your mapped your relationships. Assuming you have `IList<Movie> Actor.Movies`...

```
Movie movie = mr.GetMove(MovieId);
act.Movies.Remove(movie);
ar.Update(act);
```

Comment: Yes, it's that simple. I've found that out a few hours after posting that question. Thank you very much anyway.